# How to add duplicate records by basing on the count from another table (SQL)

Tags: oracle, oracle-11g

I wanted to add a duplicate record by basing on the count from another table

For example:

In table #1, I have the following records:

```
+------------------------+------------+
| first_name | last_name | Role       |
+------------------------+------------+
| John       | Smith     | Dev        |
| Jane       | Doe       | Tester     |
| Rock       | Lee       | Dev        |
+------------------------+------------+
```

And in table #2, I have the following records.

```
+------------------------+
| first_name | last_name | 
+------------------------+
| John       | Smith     |
| John       | Smith     |
| Jane       | Doe       |
| Jane       | Doe       |
| Rock       | Lee       |
+------------------------+
```

And since there 2 records for John Smith and Jane Doe in table #2, my expected output for table #1 is like this:

```
+------------------------+------------+
| first_name | last_name | Role       |
+------------------------+------------+
| John       | Smith     | Dev        |
| John       | Smith     | Dev        |
| Jane       | Doe       | Tester     |
| Jane       | Doe       | Tester     |
| Rock       | Lee       | Dev        |
+------------------------+------------+
```

Answer (score 0):

You could JOIN the tables
eg

```
select T1.first_name, T1.last_name, T1.role
from table#1 T1
  join table#2 T2
    on T1.first_name = T2.first_name and T1.last_name = T2.last_name
;

-- result
+----------+---------+------+
|FIRST_NAME|LAST_NAME|ROLE  |
+----------+---------+------+
|John      |Smith    |Dev   |
|John      |Smith    |Dev   |
|Jane      |Doe      |Tester|
|Jane      |Doe      |Tester|
|Rock      |Lee      |Dev   |
+----------+---------+------+
```

DBfiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=06130ebc7b3d07d21b60bbd128e7e408).